# How can I append new elments returned by Jquery/AJAX with shapeshift plugin to keep the grid-layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid-layout

How can I apply shapeshift to elements returned by AJAX placed in a div and give them the grid layout look ?

Also , it seems that Shapeflit breaks when I use it inside Jquery tabs .. like if I use it inside a tab , when I click on a tab , the grid layout is broken .. How can I fix those two issues ? Otherwise GOOD job with this plugin !!!

For example with AJAX .. when I scroll , new elements are appended with AJAX .. How can I make shapelift be applied to the new appended elements in the loaded_data div

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
// make an ajax call to your server and fetch the next 100, then update
//some vars
var url = '<?php echo $image_url;?>';
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: "scroll_data.php",
data:{image_url: '<?php echo $image_url;?>'},
success: function(result){

          var obj = $($.parseHTML(result));

           //  how can I append elements with shapelift so they can keep the grid layout ?

            $(".loaded_data").append(obj);
           $('.tweet_link').embedly({
             key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              query: {maxwidth:270, maxheight:1100} 
         });




        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Is your server code really accepting arbitrary php scripts and executing them? (That's what the fragment above seems to imply.) That would be a monstrous security vulnerability.

Comment: I dont understand what u mean at all

Comment: The only reason to send `<?php echo $image_url;?>` to a server would be for the server to execute that script. An attacker could just as easily send a script that, for example, deletes all files on the server. If you ever get the code above to work, let me know and I'll be glad to demonstrate ;^)

Comment: Can you just tell me how I can append it with shapeshift ??  that's all I really need to know , otherwise it appends fine ..I just need to know how to apply shafeshit to the appended elements ..

Comment: beats me. I don't even know what shapeshift is. Just wanted to point out that you have a massive security vulnerability in your code.

Comment: Thats not the final code at all , what I need is help related to the title of my question right now ..